# How to perform subquery for FROM statement in Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'd like to perform a query over four tables.

- `User`
- `Employments`
- `Company`
- `Votes`

`User` and `Company` are related via `Employments`. `Votes` is not directly related to the other three Entities (e.g. via PK and FK). But `Votes` is indirectly relateable to `Company`, as it contains a column `company`, that has the same string value as the `name` column of `Company`

I get to manage the query in native SQL directly, but in Doctrine2 I don't see any lights.

The query in native SQL looks about this

```
SELECT 
  c.name AS company, 
  AVG(vo.vote) AS value, 
  COUNT(vo.vote) AS votes,
  em.employees AS employees
FROM company c
 LEFT JOIN employment e ON c.id = e.company_id
 LEFT JOIN user u ON e.user_id = u.id
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT v.company, v.face
            FROM vote v
            WHERE v.gender IS NULL
              AND v.age IS NULL
              AND YEAR( v.timestamp ) = 2013
              AND MONTH( v.timestamp ) = 09
              AND DAY( v.timestamp ) = 26
  ) vo ON vo.company = c.name
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT employment.company_id, COUNT(employment.user_id) AS employees FROM employment GROUP BY employment.company_id) em ON em.company_id = c.id
WHERE u.id = 1
GROUP BY c.name
```

As said: This works nice and easy in pure SQL. So I tried to "translate" this into DQL:

```
$subqueryVotes = "SELECT v.company, v.vote
                FROM vote v
                WHERE v.gender IS NULL
                  AND v.age IS NULL
                  AND YEAR( v.timestamp ) = :year
                  AND MONTH( v.timestamp ) = :month
                  AND DAY( v.timestamp ) = :day";

$subqueryEmployeecount = "SELECT employment.company_id, COUNT(employment.user_id) AS employees FROM employment GROUP BY employment.company_id";

$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT
        c.name AS company, 
        AVG(vo.vote) AS value,
        COUNT(vo.vote) AS votes,
        em.employees AS employees
    FROM MyBundle:Company c,
        ('.$subqueryVotes.') vo,
        ('.$subqueryEmployeecount.') em
        LEFT JOIN c.employments e
        LEFT JOIN e.employee u
        WHERE vo.gender IS NULL
            AND vo.age IS NULL
            AND YEAR( vo.timestamp ) = :year
            AND MONTH( vo.timestamp ) = :month
            AND DAY( vo.timestamp ) = :day
        AND u.id = :id
        AND vo.company = c.name
        AND em.company_id = c.id
        GROUP BY c.name'
);

$query->setParameters(array(
    'year'      => $year,
    'month'     => $month,
    'day'       => $day,
    'id'        => $this->getUser()->getId()
));

$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

But now I get:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 149 near '(
SELECT': Error: Class '(' is not defined.
```

This is because I have the subselect in brackets in my `FROM` clause. Are subqueries in the `FROM` statement not allowed? How do I have to change my query to perform correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select on the from statement are not handled by doctrine 2

There is a closed (and not accepted) feature request on doctrine's jira : http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2793

> DQL is about querying objects. Supporting subselects in the FROM
>   clause means that the DQL parser is not able to build the result set
>   mapping anymore (as the fields returned by the subquery may not match
>   the object anymore). This is why it cannot be supported (supporting it
>   only for the case you run the query without the hydration is a no-go
>   IMO as it would mean that the query parsing needs to be dependant of
>   the execution mode).
>
> In your case, the best solution is probably to run a SQL query instead (as you are getting a scalar, you don't need the ORM hydration anyway)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I added the info about the recommendation to use pure SQL instead.